# Optional in Java conditional operator leads to NullPointerException

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, option-type, conditional-operator

I have a List<> of an Dto containing two parameters: type and value. Now I would like to find one element of the list with type "C" and read out the value.

When executing the following java code I get a NullPointerException which I do not understand:

```
class TestDto
{
    private String type;
    private Double value;

    TestDto(final String type, final Double value)
    {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() { return type; }
    public Double getValue() { return value; }
}
```

...

```
List<TestDto> testList = new ArrayList<>();
testList.add(new TestDto("A", 11.111d));
testList.add(new TestDto("B", 22.222d));
testList.add(new TestDto("C", null));

Predicate<TestDto> typePredicate = c-> c.getType().equals("C");
Optional optional = testList.stream().filter(typePredicate).findFirst();

if(optional.isPresent()){
    System.out.println("if-output = " + ((TestDto) optional.get()).getValue());
}

Double value = optional.isPresent() ? ((TestDto) optional.get()).getValue() : 0;

System.out.println(value);
```

The exception appears in the following line:

```
Double value = optional.isPresent() ? ((TestDto) optional.get()).getValue() : 0;
```

The value of the list element with type "C" is null, so I would expect the Double value to become null - which would be ok. This works inside of the if statement, it prints "if-output = null" as expected.

I would expect the if statement to be identical with the conditional operator. Do you have an idea why I get the NullPointerException?

Some remarks:

- I have reduced the problem to the minimum. I do understand that there are easier ways to get the value of the Dto. I would just like to understand why the code shown above doesn't work.
- If you search for type "A" or "B" there is no error and the value is printed out twice
- The replacement value "0" should be "0d" instead but it compiles with "0". However when changing the code to:

> ```
> Double value = optional.isPresent() ? null : 0;
> ```

it does not compile until I change the replacement value to "0d". Maybe this helps to unserstand the problem.

Comment: Try not using raw types. It should be `Optional<TestDto>`

Comment: Are you sure you have `private double value;` in your `TestDto`, and not `private Double value;`? Otherwise, passing `null` for `final Double value` would result in the crash inside the constructor ([demo](https://ideone.com/951xnu)).

Comment: I get a NullPointerException on `testList.add(new TestDto("C", null));`

Comment: @markbernard My bad. I wrote the class DTO myself to turn this into something runnable. Fixed it.

Comment: I did not post the TestDto code, but I will change it in the text above to Double, otherwise you are right and it would crash already in the constructor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a slightly funny one. Your ternary operator here:

```
optional.isPresent() ? ((TestDto) optional.get()).getValue() : 0;
```

is using a primitive zero. Java is deciding to first unbox your null `Double` to a primitive double, so that both results are of the same type, and that causes a `NullPointerException`.

If you replace `0` with `Double.valueOf(0)`, both results of the ternary are of the type `Double` and so no unboxing needs to take place.

```
optional.isPresent() ? ((TestDto) optional.get()) : Double.valueOf(0);
```

---

As an aside, all of the horrible casting which makes your code look so ugly in places is a result of you not using the generic version of `Optional`. If you use generic version, your code could look like this:

```
Optional<TestDto> optional = testList.stream().filter(typePredicate).findFirst();
       // ^ Generics!

if(optional.isPresent()){
    System.out.println("if-output = " + optional.get().getValue());
}

Double value = optional.isPresent() ? optional.get().getValue() : Double.valueOf(0);

System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: Wow I didn't even think of that. Great answer.

Comment: Btw, to make it even nicer, one may also do: `Double value = optional.map(TestDto::getValue).orElseGet(0D);`

Comment: @davida. Careful! That's not an exact replacement. If `getValue` returns null, you'll end up with 0 when you do in fact want null.

Comment: @davida. Here's a runnable example proving the two are not interchangeable: https://ideone.com/Nhshee

Comment: Thanks for the hint to use the generic optional!

Comment: @mgerbracht Enable *all* Java compiler warnings in your IDE.  It will then tell you about mistakes like raw types.